# OnCreateOptionsMenu is called for the wrong Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have SherlockFragmentActivity with 3 fragments and ViewPager to swipe between them (in addition to ActionBar).

Every SherlockFragment has its own menu and looks like this:

```java
public class MyFragment1 extends SherlockFragment {
    private Menu menu;
    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }
//...
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.fr1, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        this.menu = menu;
    }
//...
}
```

Other fragment classes look similar.

You know, ViewPager instantiates two fragments at first activity launch. So, first executes `OnCreateView()` of the first fragment, then `OnCreateOptionsMenu()` of the first fragment, then `OnCreateView()` of the second fragment, and then `OnCreateOptionsMenu()` of the FIRST fragment AGAIN!

Please help, I need to understand what I do wrong.

Comment: how do you handle the menu inflation?

Comment: @DanielBo what do you mean? in my activity I keep default OnCreateOptionsMenu() implementation.

Comment: how do you trigger the onCreateOptionsMenu, or how does the viewpager know when to inflate another menu? I invalidate my optionsmenu everytime onPageSelected is called, and onCreateOptionsMenu then tells the currently shown fragment to inflate its menu, works like a charm :)

Comment: @DanielBo Hmmm, in OnPageSelected I only select Tab via my SupportActionBar... And how do you invalidate it?

Answer (score 0):

Checking if the viewpager is hosted by SherlockFragmentActivity to make sure i can make that cast and the followed call :)

```
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    ...
    if (context instanceof SherlockFragmentActivity)
        ((SherlockFragmentActivity)context).supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
}
```

and you need to start the inflation in the contexts onCreateOptionsMenu like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    Fragment f = get your current Fragment
    if (f != null && f instanceof SherlockFragment)
            ((SherlockFragment)f).onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, getSupportMenuInflater());
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: now my menu items are duplicating and mixing with those on other fragments((

Comment: well i guess your previous inflating process is working besides the new one, which results in doubled menus :S

Comment: I think every f*cking time I scroll the ViewPager, it calls fragment menu inflater TWICE to build TWO fragments for better perfomance...

Comment: mine caches the fragments to the left and right of the current Fragment, i dont have any issues with a doubled menuItem